# embedded youtube with autoplay/pause on scroll/leave not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have an embedded youtube video on my website,which should start playing if the user scrolls to it and pause when user leaves, also once its played to the end it'll get marked as played and won't start a second time just from scrolling.

It works great in all browsers, except safari. I have one markup version, which will display the video in safari but autoplay on scroll won't work, then with my other try, it will play automatically and i can hear the sound but instead of the video i can see a white screen only

Here is a fiddle of the whole markup: https://jsfiddle.net/Lefwxrez/
Live Version online at http://primera-healthcare.eu/en/signature-slide-printer.html

Here is the code snippet where the autoplay won't work in safari:

```html
 <section id="sectVid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="auto-resizable-iframe">
             <div>
                <div id="ytplayer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <script>
             function onPlayerReady(event) {
                if (element_in_view) {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                }
             }
             function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    played = true;
                }
             }
             // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
             var tag = document.createElement('script');
             tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
             var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
             var element_position = $('#sectVid').offset().top;
             var screen_height = $(window).height();
             var activation_offset = 0.6;//determines how far up the the page the element needs to be before triggering the function
             var activation_point = element_position - (screen_height * activation_offset);
             var maxY = element_position + (screen_height * activation_offset);
             var max_scroll_height = $('body').height() - screen_height - 5;//-5 for a little bit of buffer
             var element_in_view = false;
             var played = false;
             var player;
             function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                   height: '390',
                   width: '640',
                   videoId: 'Yq_b32EavMo',
                   playerVars: {
                      'origin': 'http://www.youtube.com/',
                      'rel': 0,
                      'modestbranding': 1
                   },
                   events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                   }
                });
             }
             //Does something when user scrolls to it
             $(window).on('scroll', function () {
             var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
             element_in_view = (y_scroll_pos > activation_point && y_scroll_pos < maxY && !played);
             if (element_in_view) {
                 player.playVideo();
             } else {
                 player.pauseVideo();
             }
          });
        </script>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

if i now add a second version for mobile display and hide the first one on mobile view it will autoplay with a white screen, code is as the following:

```html
 <section id="sectVid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="auto-resizable-iframe">
                        <div>
                            <div id="ytplayer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>



 if(screen && screen.width >= 768){
                        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                            if (element_in_view) {
                                event.target.playVideo();
                            }
                        }

                        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                played = true;
                            }
                        }

                        // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                        var tag = document.createElement('script');
                        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                        var element_position = $('#sectVid').offset().top;

                        var screen_height = $(window).height();
                        var activation_offset = 0.6;//determines how far up the the page the element needs to be before triggering the function
                        var activation_point = element_position - (screen_height * activation_offset);
                        var maxY = element_position + (screen_height * activation_offset);
                        var max_scroll_height = $('body').height() - screen_height - 5;//-5 for a little bit of buffer
                        var element_in_view = false;
                        var played = false;

                        var player;

                        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                                height: '390',
                                width: '640',
                                videoId: 'Yq_b32EavMo',
                                playerVars: {
                                    'origin': 'http://www.youtube.com/',
                                    'rel': 0,
                                    'modestbranding': 1
                                },
                                events: {
                                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        //Does something when user scrolls to it
                        $(window).on('scroll', function () {


                            var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;

                            element_in_view = (y_scroll_pos > activation_point && y_scroll_pos < maxY && !played);


                            if (element_in_view) {
                                player.playVideo();
                            } else {
                                player.pauseVideo();
                            }


                        });
                       }



                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="mobilesctVid">
           <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="auto-resizable-iframe">
                 <div>
                   <div id="mobileytplayer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <script>
                     if (screen && screen.width < 768) {
                         // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                         var tag = document.createElement('script');
                         tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                         var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                         firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                         var element_position = $('#mobilesectVid').offset().top;

                         var screen_height = $(window).height();
                         var activation_offset = 0.6;//determines how far up the the page the element needs to be before triggering the function
                         var activation_point = element_position - (screen_height * activation_offset);
                         var maxY = element_position + (screen_height * activation_offset);
                         var max_scroll_height = $('body').height() - screen_height - 5;//-5 for a little bit of buffer
                         var element_in_view = false;
                         var played = false;


                         // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
                         // YouTube player after the API code downloads.

                         var player;

                         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                             player = new YT.Player('mobileytplayer', {
                                 height: '390',
                                 width: '640',
                                 videoId: 'Yq_b32EavMo',
                                 playerVars: {
                                     'origin': 'http://www.youtube.com/',
                                     'rel': 0,
                                     'modestbranding': 1
                                 },
                                 events: {
                                     'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                     }

                 </script>
             </div>
           </div>
         </section>
```

As i stated, it works in other browsers for me, both markup versions. I tested it in FireFox, FireFox Dev, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: can you post the entire code? Naturally I get some error when I try to test it because new YT.Player is not recognised. 
Question: where do you call the method 'onYouTubeIframeAPIReady', variable player isn't never initialized!
let me know

Comment: so i tried to post the entire code but it was too much characters for stack overflow. I tried to create a fiddle, hope everything is alright with it (i never used jsfiddle before) otherwise let me know :) also thanks in advance